# Tensorflow Serving Compile Error Using Docker on OSX

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to install TensorFlow serving on OSX El Capitan using Docker but keep running into an error. Here is the tutorial I'm following:

https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/docker.html

Here is the command causing the error:

```
bazel test tensorflow_serving/...
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
for (int i = 0; i < suffix.size(); ++i) {
                                   ^
ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/f8d1071c69ea316497c31e40fe01608c/external/tf/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:212:1: C++ compilation of rule '@tf//tensorflow/core/kernels:mirror_pad_op' failed: gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer '-std=c++0x' -iquote external/tf -iquote ... (remaining 65 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 4.
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved! Looks like the issues was with running out of memory in the VM.

Here's how I fixed it:

1) When creating the machine, make sure it has more memory (mine was only 1GB). Here is how you create a docker machine with 4GB:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 4096 default
```

2) When running the bazel command pass in a parameter limiting the amount of memory to use. Here I'm running the command using only 2GB:

```
bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --verbose_failures --local_resources 2048,2.0,1.0 -j 1 //tensorflow_serving/example:mnist_export
```

Where the original command was:

```
bazel build //tensorflow_serving/example:mnist_export
```