# How to use Tensorflow trained Machine Learning Model in iOS

Tags: ios, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, coreml

I am trying to recognise image which has been trained using Tensorflow. I followed this [steps](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#6/%22steps%22)
and finally i got success to train my own dataset and its give a good prediction result. All of the code is in python. Now i am trying to use this trained model in my iOS project . I am following this [tutorial](https://petewarden.com/2016/09/27/tensorflow-for-mobile-poets/?blogsub=confirming#subscribe-blog/%22tutorial%22) to use my trained model in my iOS project. But when i followed those steps i got an error in my mac terminal window like -

`"ERROR: /tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:2235:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/core/kernels:self_adjoint_eig_v2_op' failed: gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -B/usr/bin -B/usr/bin -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG ... (remaining 124 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 4. gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)"`.

What will be the solution for this issue or is there any way to convert this tensor-flow model to iOS supported Core ML Model ? Here i'm sharing a screen shot of that error. Please help me out. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is due to insufficient memory inside the docker container for bazel to run with default parameters. Try rerunning (after `bazel clean`) the build with these extra flags to the build command: `--local_resources 2048,2.0,1.0 -j 1`. You can also try giving a little more resources: `--local_resources 4096,2.0,1.0 -j 1`

Here are some links for this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1530 
[Tensorflow Serving Compile Error Using Docker on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36264339/tensorflow-serving-compile-error-using-docker-on-osx/36268413#36268413)